# Pass more arguments to an already opened cmd prompt in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I want to loop through all images in a folder, retrieve each image's name and pass an argument using the name. This is what I have:

```
foreach (string imageFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath))
{
    //Get image name and save it as string
    string args = "something"; //a line of argument with image name in it
    Process.Start("cmd", @"/c cd C:\Tesseract-OCR && " + args);
}
```

The problem with above code is that, for each image file, it will open up a new command prompt. Instead, I want something like:

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"/k cd C:\Tesseract-OCR");
foreach (string imageFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath))
{
    //For each imageFile I have, pass an argument to the opened cmd prompt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods, but generally the simplest is to create a batch file with all of the commands you want to execute then pass that as a parameter to `cmd`.

Something like this:

```
string imageFolder = @"C:\Path\To\Images";
string batchFile = @"C:\Temp\cmds.cmd";
string outputFile = @"C:\Temp\cmds.log";

// substitute your own command here.  "{0}" will be substituted for filename 
string command = @"attrib ""{0}"" >> """ + outputFile + @"""";

// delete the batch file if it exists
if (File.Exists(batchFile))
    File.Delete(batchFile);

// create batch file from content of image folder
using (var writer = File.CreateText(batchFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine("@echo off");

    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, "*.jpg"))
        writer.WriteLine(command, file);
}

// Delete the output file if it exists
if (File.Exists(outputFile))
    File.Delete(outputFile);

// Execute the batch
var p = Process.Start("cmd", @"/c """ + batchFile + @"""");
p.WaitForExit();
```

After that completes you can grab the content of the output file and parse it for results.  If you need a break between the outputs, just echo something distinctive between each one.  Maybe something like:

```
// create batch file from content of image folder
using (var writer = File.CreateText(batchFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine("@echo off");

    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, "*.jpg"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(@"echo -----Start: {0}>>""{1}""", file, outputFile);
        writer.WriteLine(command, file);
        writer.WriteLine(@"echo -----End: {0}>>""{1}""", file, outputFile);
    }
}
```

That way you get the filename in the output as well to help with parsing.

---

Another option is to use full stream redirection to streams that you can write commands to and read responses from.  This would allow you to have a command prompt running somewhere in the background that you can issue commands to.  Seems simple, but honestly it takes a lot of work to get just right.  If you want to go this way I'd suggest redirecting all three standard streams.

Comment: Thank you! That works extremely well! Just a quick question: Why `@"tesseract ""{0}"" """ + outputFile + @"""";` 
instead of a shorter `@"tesseract {0} " + outputFile;`? I see a lot of codes were written in your format and have always wondered why.

Comment: So that you can use spaces in the filename if you want to, for either the source or output files.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the program create a batch file containing all the files/commands to be executed, then use Process.Start to execute the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a string array of all the files in a directory. Then use [String.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to merge the array into one long string of file names separated by space. I would also wrap each item in quotes if your path or files contain spaces.

```
const string QUOTE = "\"";
const string SPACE = " ";
const string SEPARATOR = QUOTE + SPACE + QUOTE;

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.png");
string allFiles = QUOTE + String.Join(SEPARATOR, files) + QUOTE;
Console.WriteLine(@"cmd.exe /c cd C:\Tesseract-OCR && " + allFiles);
```